# $\mathcal{f}:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ restricted to sections is continuous implies continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $\mathcal{f}:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathcal{f}$ restricted to **each** {$x=a$} is continuous and restricted to *each* section {$y=b$} is continuous and monotone.Prove that $\mathcal{f}$ is continuous.

My thoughts:I tried to prove $\mathcal{f}$ is differentiable but it was a rather bad strategy.

update:corrected restriction to x=a for each restriction x=a

Comment: Is this just for one $a$ (in the first part of the assumption)? I think then it would be wrong, you probably need it for all $a$ and for all $b$.

Comment: You are right,i'm sorry,i'll correct the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}$**Hint:** If $(x, y)$ and $(x_{0}, y_{0})$ are arbitrary points, then
$$
f(x, y) - f(x_{0}, y_{0})
  = \bigl(f(x, y) - f(x, y_{0})\bigr) + \bigl(f(x, y_{0}) - f(x_{0}, y_{0})\bigr).
$$
In the first term on the right, only $y$ varies; in the second, only $x$ varies.

---

**Edit:** More hint, since the epsilontics are a bit delicate.

Assume without loss of generality that $f$ is non-decreasing in $y$.

Fix $(x_{0}, y_{0})$ and  $\eps > 0$. Use continuity of $f$ in $y$ to pick $\delta_{2} > 0$ such that
$$
|y - y_{0}| < \delta_{2} \text{ implies }
  |f(x_{0}, y) - f(x_{0}, y_{0})| < \tfrac{1}{3}\eps.
$$
Now use continuity in $x$ (and the standard "minimum of two conditions" idiom) to pick $\delta_{1} > 0$ such that
$$
|x - x_{0}| < \delta_{1} \text{ implies }
  |f(x, y_{0} \pm \delta_{2}) - f(x_{0}, y_{0} \pm \delta_{2})| < \tfrac{1}{3}\eps.
$$
If $|x - x_{0}| < \delta_{1}$ and $0 \leq y - y_{0} < \delta_{2}$, then
$$
f(x, y) - f(x_{0}, y_{0})
  = \bigl(f(x, y) - f(x_{0}, y)\bigr) + \bigl(f(x_{0}, y) - f(x_{0}, y_{0})\bigr).
\tag{1}
$$
Now for the delicate part: Since $f$ is monotonic in $y$,
\begin{align*}
\bigl(f(x, y) - f(x_{0}, y)\bigr)
  &\leq \bigl(f(x, y_{0} + \delta_{2}) - f(x_{0}, y_{0})\bigr) \\
  &= \bigl(f(x, y_{0} + \delta_{2}) - f(x_{0}, y_{0} + \delta_{2})\bigr)
  + \bigl(f(x_{0}, y_{0} + \delta_{2}) - f(x_{0}, y_{0})\bigr)
\tag{2a}
\end{align*}
(increase $y$ in the first term and decrease it in the second, then use my initial hint), and
$$
\bigl(f(x_{0}, y) - f(x_{0}, y_{0})\bigr)
  \leq \bigl(f(x_{0}, y+ \delta_{2}) - f(x_{0}, y_{0})\bigr).
\tag{2b}
$$
Entirely similar estimates handle the case $-\delta < y - y_{0} < 0$.

Putting everything together, if $|x - x_{0}| < \delta_{1}$ and $|y - y_{0}| < \delta_{2}$, then
\begin{align*}
|f(x, y) - f(x_{0}, y_{0})|
  &\leq \big|f(x, y) - f(x_{0}, y)\big| + \big|f(x_{0}, y) - f(x_{0}, y_{0})\big| \\
  &\leq \big|f(x, y_{0} + \delta_{2}) - f(x_{0}, y_{0} + \delta_{2})\big|
  + \big|f(x_{0}, y_{0} + \delta_{2}) - f(x_{0}, y_{0})\big| \\
  &\qquad + \big|f(x_{0}, y+ \delta_{2}) - f(x_{0}, y_{0})\big| \\
  &< \eps.
\end{align*}

Comment: I am not sure the hint helps that much. Note that the statement is wrong if you just assume continuity on each horizontal and vertical line. In order to prove the statement, the monotonicity in the $x$-variable is crucial.

Comment: What you say does not use monotonicity: it is known that partial continuity in each variable does not imply joint continuity, therefore this monotonicity assumption must be essential. Your argument would be correct, I believe, if at least one variable of $f$ would be taken from a compact space - if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Pick any point $(x_0, y_0)$ in the plane and a constant $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exists $\delta_1 > 0$ such that $|f(x,y_0) - f(x_0,y_0)| \le \epsilon / 2$ whenever $|x-x_0| \le \delta_1$. Now there exist $\delta_2 > 0$ such that $|f(x_0 \pm \delta_1, y) - f(x_0 \pm \delta_1, y_0)| \le \epsilon/2$ whenever $|y-y_0| \le \delta_2$. This gives $|f(x_0 \pm \delta_1,y) - f(x_0,y_0)| \le \epsilon$ for $|y-y_0| \le \delta_2$, i.e., you get the desired continuity estimate on the left and right sides of the rectangle of width $2\delta_1$ and height $2\delta_2$ centered at $(x_0,y_0)$. The same estimate for the interior now follows from monotonicity in the $x$-variable.

Comment: Thank you very much Lukas,your answer is quite neat,but i have somewhat of a difficult understanding this part of analysis so i choose one that i was able to dissect with my tools.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. By changing $f$ by $g(x,y)=g(x+x_0,y+y_0)-f(x_0,y_0)$ if necessary, we can assume that $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0$ (this is just so I don't have to type as much).

Let $\delta_1>0$ such that $|f(x,0)|\leq\epsilon$ whenever $|x|\leq\delta_1$. Now choose $\delta_2>0$ such that $|f(\delta_1,y)-f(\delta_1,0)|<\epsilon$ and $|f(-\delta_1,y)-f(-\delta_1,0)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|y|<\delta_2$.

Consider the rectangle $[-\delta_1,\delta_1]\times[-\delta_2,\delta_2]$, which contains $(0,0)$ in its interior. Suppose $|x|<\delta_1$ and $|y|<\delta_2$. Then
$$|f(\delta_1,y)|\leq|f(\delta_1,y)-f(\delta_1,0)|+|f(\delta_1,0)|\leq 2\epsilon,$$
and similarly $|f(-\delta_1,y)|\leq 2\epsilon$. Since $f$ is monotone along the line $(\cdot,y)$, and $(x,y)$ is between $(-\delta_1,y)$ and $(\delta_1,y)$, we have $|f(x,y)-f(\delta_1,y)|\leq|f(-\delta_1,y)-f(\delta_1,y)|$, so

### \begin{align*}
|f(x,y)|&\leq|f(x,y)-f(\delta_1,y)|+|f(\delta_1,y)|\\
&\leq |f(-\delta_1,y)-f(\delta_1,y)|+2\epsilon\\
&\leq 6\epsilon
\end{align*}

**Remark**: We are doing approximations here, which works well and is quite visual. But actually, using the fact that $f$ is monotone on the line $(\cdot,y)$ yields $|f(x,y)|\leq\max(|f(-\delta_1,y)|,|f(\delta_1,y)|)\leq 2\epsilon$.